# Mathematial operations in preg_match

Tags: php, preg-replace

I need to lower preg variable by one. Example:

```
$code = A4-7;
$new = preg_replace('/A([0-9])\-([0-9])/', 'S($1-1)-$2', $code);
```

I need to do something like that, so preg replace returns S3-7. Is there some way?

Comment: Use `preg_replace_callback`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (using preg_replace_callback)

```
$code = "A4-7";

function myfunc($matches)
{

  return 'S'.($matches[1]-1).'-'.$matches[2];
}
echo preg_replace_callback("#A(\d)-(\d)#","myfunc",$code);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to extract the values first, perform the mathematical operations on the extracted values and then reconstruct the string to achieve what you want.

For example:

```
<?php
$code = 'A4-7';
preg_match('/A([0-9])\-([0-9])/', $code, $matches);
$new = 'S'.($matches[1]-1).'-'.$matches[2];
?>
```